# Was the English name "Starky" in Chrono Cross part of the of pattern of giving characters rock star names?

Tags: chrono-cross

Various characters in the English-language versions of the video games Chrono Trigger* and its sequel Chrono Cross are named after rock stars (most notably Ozzie, Flea, and Slash—the "tone-deaf evil fiends").  I just noticed yesterday that one of the characters from the second game, [Starky](https://www.chronowiki.org/wiki/Starky), might also fit this pattern.  His Japanese name meant "star child," but his English name—while it still contains "star"—is also very close to Ringo Starr's real name:  "Richard Starkey."

Is there any evidence from the game's producers or translators that this is anything more than a coincidence?

*I had thought there were more questions on SF&F about Chrono Trigger, but it turns out that there is [only one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115385/what-was-magus-failed-attack-on-lavos), and I was the only person who answered it.